# Python - For loop - run each line of output

Tags: python, for-loop

I guess I am running into a beginner problem:
-> I want to loop over an array and insert the the values into lines of code that are executed.
For the attempt below I get "SyntaxError: can't assign to operator"

```
#Country-subsets (all countries in dataframe)
for s in country_filter:  
  s.lower() + '_immu_edu' = immu_edu.loc[immu_edu['CountryName'] == s]
```

Thanks for helping!

My expected output would be:

```
guinea_immu_edu = immu_edu.loc[immu_edu['CountryName'] == "Guinea"]
lao_immu_edu = immu_edu.loc[immu_edu['CountryName'] == "Lao PDR"]
bf_immu_edu = immu_edu.loc[immu_edu['CountryName'] == "Burkina Faso"]
us_immu_edu = immu_edu.loc[immu_edu['CountryName'] == "United States"]
ge_immu_edu = immu_edu.loc[immu_edu['CountryName'] == "Germany"]
```

Comment: _insert the the values into lines of code that are executed_ What do you mean? - Also what is your expected output?

Comment: What does it mean to 'insert values into lines of code that are executed'? Can you show what your expected output is>?

Comment: @B001ᛦ Lol, I love how we have an identical comment.

Comment: You need to store the result `s.lower() + '_immu_edu'` somewhere as it is a temporary (also known as an "rvalue" in some languages). You can't assign to it.

Comment: So if `s` is the string `"foo"`, you want to create a variable named `foo_immu_edu`? That kind of "dynamic variable creation" is almost never a good idea. Use a dict instead: `d[s.lower() + '_immu_edu'] = whatever`

Comment: Ahhh alright, I think I get it. Will try the dict solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I create a variable number of variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-a-variable-number-of-variables)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store your values in a dictionary and access using the keys:

```
my_dict = dict()
for s in country_filter:  
  my_dict[s.lower() + '_immu_edu'] = immu_edu.loc[immu_edu['CountryName'] == s]
```